# CODEIGNITER function can echo but can't return

Tags: php, sql, function, codeigniter, return

I have this code in my model file

```
function exist_kode($kode = 1)        
{
     $get = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM perkiraan WHERE kode_perk='$kode'");

     if($get->num_rows() == 0)
     {
        return $kode;
     }
     else
     {
        $this->exist_kode((int)$kode+1);
     }
}
```

This function is not return some values when I use. But if I change return to echo, it will write the value I hope.

> How can i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return in your else statement as well:

`return $this->exist_kode((int)$kode+1);`

Comment: thanks for your solution, now my function work fluently

Comment: Don't forget to mark as answered and/or upvote! Glad it's working!